# Clean character vector and strsplit into dataframe

Tags: regex, r

I have a character verctor I want to transform into a data frame.
It's mostly clean but I can't figure out how to finish the cleaning. Notice that the real data are a `Date` column as `yyyy-mm-dd` and a `Variable` column as a number (in this case four digits but not always) separated by a comma.

```
class(myvec)
[1] "character"
myvec
[1] " \"2016-01-01,8631n\" " " \"2016-01-02,8577n\" "
[3] " \"2016-01-03,8476n\" " " \"2016-01-04,8365n\" "
[5] " \"2016-01-05,8331n\" " " \"2016-01-06,8801n\" "
[7] " \"2016-01-07,5020n\""
```

The space and backslash" (' \"') should be removed. The same with the n\"
The expected output should be a data frame like this

```
    Date         Variable  
[1,] "2016-01-01" "8631"
[2,] "2016-01-02" "8577"
[3,] "2016-01-03" "8476"
[4,] "2016-01-04" "8365"
[5,] "2016-01-05" "8331"
[6,] "2016-01-06" "8801"
[7,] "2016-01-07" "5020"
```

Once the vector is clan, I think this does the job

```
do.call(rbind,strsplit(clean_vector,","))
```

I think I can convert to date with `lubridate` and the `var` to numeric with as.numeric on my own, the question is about getting the character vector clean and in the correct format.

Comment: `gsub("[n \"]","",x) # "2016-01-01,8631"` works fine for the first one. You could also just use `substr` since all your objects seem to be fixed-width.

Comment: @Frank Please post an answer, this is great! also maybe provide some explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the offending characters by enumerating them:

```
# example
x = " \"2016-01-01,8631n\" "

gsub("[n \"]","",x)
# "2016-01-01,8631"
```

This works because `[xyz]` identifies any single character from the list `xyz`.

---

Or you can take a substring, since the formatting is fixed-width, with bad chars at the start and end:

```
substr(x,3,17)
# "2016-01-01,8631"
```

If the `var` part of the string varies in length, `nchar(x)-3` should work in place of `17`.

Comment: The second one was my original approach but I noticed that "the items have a fixed width" was not true and I couldn't predict when the numbers were going to have more digits

Comment: @MatiasAndina You can use `nchar(x)-3` or something if there are always three bad chars at the end.

Comment: Haven't seen you for  a while.  Plus one.